# I am getting wrong answer by using the below mentioned query. Can someone explain why?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Product

product_id is the primary key of this table.

Table: Sales

This table has no primary key, it can have repeated rows.
product_id is a foreign key to Product table.

Write an SQL query that reports the buyers who have bought S8 but not iPhone.

Note that S8 and iPhone are products present in the Product table.

The query result format is in the following example:

Product table:

Product_id|product_name|Unit_price
(1,S8,1000),(2,G4,800),(3,iphone,1400)

Sales table:

|seller_id|product_id|buyer_id|sale_date|quantity|price|

(1,1,1,2019-01-21,2,2000)

(1,2,2,2019-02-17,1,800)

(2,1,3,2019-06-02,1,800)

(3,3,3,2019-05-13,2,2800)

Result table:

| buyer_id|

| 1 |

The buyer with id 1 bought an S8 but didn't buy an iPhone. The buyer with id 3 bought both.

My query:

```
SELECT 
    distinct buyer_id
FROM
    sales
WHERE product_id=1 and buyer_id not in (SELECT 
            buyer_id
        FROM
            sales
        WHERE
            product_id = 3);
```

Query that Works:

```
select distinct buyer_id
from Sales inner join Product
where Sales.product_id = Product.product_id
    and product_name = 'S8'
    and buyer_id not in
    (select distinct buyer_id
    from Sales inner join Product
    where Sales.product_id = Product.product_id
        and product_name = 'iPhone')
```

Comment: Your query will return incorrect result once Product table is  updated: (1, G4) (3,S8).

Comment: Hi. Thank you for you reply. Yes, that was the case. I assumed that it is gonna stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

What is that makes you think your query is returning wrong result and the other one correct result? Both would return the same result of:

### buyer_id

1

No?

The difference between them is the first one is directly using the product_id, thus doesn't need to check Product table (but not realistic in real world, nobody would rely on fixed Ids like that and memorize them). Question is saying 'S8' and 'iPhone', then you should get the Ids from Product.

Comment: Hi. Yes, that was the case. Thank you pointing that out.